# Slider Value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

I have the below code that, when the switch is turned off/false, the slider moves to 0 and can't be moved until switch is turned on.
What's happening is that if the slider is set to a value and the switch is turned off, the sliderval retains the value from before switch is turned off so where it is used elsewhere in the code, it doesn't have the value of 0.
I have been able to get the sliderval to return to 0 (although i cant remember how) but once switch is turned back on, it doesn't return to value before switch was turned off.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated :)

```
children: <Widget>[
                    Switch(
                        value: switchstate,
                        onChanged: (bool s) {
                          setState(() {
                            switchstate = s;
                            print(switchstate);
                          });
                        }),
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Slider(
                        value: switchstate ? sliderval : 0,
                        onChanged: (value) => setState(
                          () => sliderval = value,
                        ),
                        min: 0,
                        max: 255,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
```

Comment: if I understand this correctly, you want the slider value equal 0 once the switch if off, to do this just add     sliderval = 0    inside onChange in the Switch

Comment: of course you need to check if s is false

Comment: thank you. The issue i had with that was that once the switch was off, the sliderval would return to 0 but when switched back on, the slider would be at 0 instead of returning to original position. I was able to overcome this by putting similar code in the void that uses the sliderval and using another variable. If that makes sense `switchstate ? frontSliderVal = sliderval : frontSliderVal = 0; `